# Python decorator to find key exist, and pass it as argument

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering if I could use a decorator to see if an input to a function is:

1. A dictionary, if not dictionary then run the method
2. If it is dictionary, extract specified keys from it, and pass it to method

example:

```
@get_values(['username', 'password'])
    def log_me_in(username, password)
       # login logic
       if username == password:
           return True
       return False
```

ways to call it:

```
log_me_in(username = 10, password = 10)
>>>> True
log_me_in(10, 10)
>>>> True
log_me_in({'username': 10, 'password': 10})
>>>> True
log_me_in({'username': 10, 'password': 10, 'something': 10})
>>>> True
log_me_in({'username': 10, 'something': 10})
>>>> EXCEPTION
log_me_in({})
>>>> EXCEPTION
log_me_in([])
>>>> EXCEPTION
```

Comment: Sure. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: If you use [`inspect.getargspec()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) you can even detect what arguments the decorated function supports.

Comment: As a side note, I think the decorator would be friendlier if it took `*args` instead of a list, so you could just write `@get_values('username', 'password')`. But that doesn't make it any easier to harder to write, so it's not all that important here.

Comment: There are a lot of gaps in this spec. Does a single positional argument which is a dictionary but accompanied by keyword arguments get treated as case 1 or 2? There are a bunch of cases that could be `TypeError` or something different, and you need to decide which ones are `TypeError`s. Does a single _keyword_ argument which is a dictionary count as case 2 always, never, or only if it has the same name as the first parameter? And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the values as positional arguments (according to the positions in the params list passed to the decorator):

```
def getvalues(params):
    getter = itemgetter(*params)
    def deco(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if len(args) == 1 and not kwargs and isinstance(args[0], Mapping):
                return func(*getter(args[0]))
            else:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return deco
```

If you want to pass them as keyword arguments instead:

```
def getvalues(params):
    def deco(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if len(args) == 1 and not kwargs and isinstance(args[0], Mapping):
                return func(**{key: value for key, value in args[0].items() 
                               if key in params})
            else:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return deco
```

I had to invent my own rules to fill in all of the gaps in the specification, but I think they're somewhat reasonable.

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, I think it would be friendlier if `getvalues` took its the parameter names as separate arguments instead of a list. To fix that, just change the first line to `def getvalues(*params):`.

Comment: where is Mapping located in 2.7.3 in the line:   isinstance(args[0], Mapping)

Comment: @user1639926: Directly in `collections`. If you look at [the docs for `collections.abc`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html) it tells you that right at the top.

Comment: I was searching google for python mapping function, python mapping library etc etc.  also if there are good ways of finding something like that in the future, that would be great!  Maybe i am just searching wrong.

Comment: @user1639926: You can go to http://docs.python.org, select your version, and use the "Quick search" box. Or you can google `site:docs.python.org Mapping`. When I do that, I get the C API (which you definitely don't care about) as the first hit, but the 3.4 docs for `collections.abc.Mapping` as the next one, and right at the top it says to go to `collections` (with a link) for pre-3.3, so you can do that, then pick 2.7 in the pulldown menu. Not perfect by any means, but it's a quick&dirty solution I use often.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes. But is it necessary? You could get a similar result by passing in keyword arguments with `**`:

```
>>> log_me_in(**{'username': 10, 'password': 10})
True
```

The one difference is that passing `something` would not be allowed. Python errors out on unrecognized keyword arguments. See:

```
>>> log_me_in(username=10, password=10)
True
>>> log_me_in(10, 10)
True
>>> log_me_in(**{'username': 10, 'password': 10})
True
>>> log_me_in(**{'username': 10, 'password': 10, 'something': 10})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: log_me_in() got an unexpected keyword argument 'something'
>>> log_me_in(**{'username': 10, 'something': 10})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: log_me_in() got an unexpected keyword argument 'something'
>>> log_me_in(**{})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: log_me_in() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'
>>> log_me_in(*[])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: log_me_in() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'username' and 'password'
```

Comment: But you cannot pass in `{'username': 10, 'password': 10, 'something': 10}` unless the function has a `**kwargs` argument.

Comment: as you suggest, I can add the kwargs argument to take care of the "something".  in this case, is there a way I can "add" ** for dicts or * for lists in the background without the user using this function needing to do this?

Comment: @johnKugelman mainly to help me format HTTP POST requests.  Everything comes through in a json dictionary, and I am trying to do some "cleaning" before it reaches my functions which could potentially break if someone accessed certain parameters in areas they shouldn't

Comment: The other difference is that you're putting the burden on the caller to use `**` instead of on the callee.